# Access attribute

Tags: java, oop

Since we know that `clone()` method declared in `Object` class is protected and every subclass of `Object` (which is all the classes) can access it here my question arouse:

if i write :

```
String str1 = "clone";  
String str2 = str1.clone();
```

compiler flags this as an error. `String` does not override `clone()`, hence this method is only accessible in lang package(i know if this class overrides `clone()` it should be public to be accessible from outside of the package, and if it is protected it is accessible in lang package). right?
but this fragment does not flag any compile error:

```
Point p1 = new Point();  
Point p2 = p1.clone();
```

why?
both `String` and `Point` class does not override `clone()` method, but `clone()` method is accessible via `Point` objects.

Comment: I think it doesn't work as strings are final and immutable and doesn't implement the Cloneable interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Point`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) inherits the public `clone()` method from [`Point2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html#clone%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

`Point` inherits a public `clone()` override from `Point2D`.

You could have discovered this for yourself in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html#clone%28%29).